# Trigger pipeline when it's merged to specific branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I was wondering how can I trigger a pipeline only when a MR succesfully merge to a specific branch? in this case a branch name that starts with 'dev' case insensitive

I have tried

```
job:
  only:
    - /^dev.*$/
  except:
    - branches
```

or

```
job:
  only:
    - /^dev.*$/
```

or

```
job:
  only:
    refs:
      - /^dev.*$/
```

none of this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitLab 12.3 or later, try [`rules:if`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#rulesif) clause:

```
job:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^dev.*$/
      when: always
```